# Animate/Tween image size in flashpunk

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, tween

So I'm new to the FlashPunk library, and don't know how to resize an Image? 
So for example how do you animate an image's height value from the real size to 0?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a [spritemap](http://useflashpunk.net/docs/net/flashpunk/graphics/Spritemap.html#Spritemap()).

[example from flashgamedojo](http://flashgamedojo.com/wiki/index.php?title=Sprite_Animation_(FlashPunk)):

```
import net.flashpunk.Entity;
import net.flashpunk.graphics.Text;

public class AnimatedEntity extends Entity{
    // Embed the animation image.
    [Embed(source = 'my_animated_character.png'] private const MY_ANIM:Class;

    protected var animatedSprite:Spritemap = new Spritemap(MY_ANIM,16,16);
    public function AnimatedEntity () {

        // You pass in the source image and the height and width of each frame of the animation.
        animatedSprite = new Spritemap(MY_ANIM, 16, 16);

        // Let's set our Entity's graphic to our new Spritemap, dawg.
        graphic = animatedSprite;

        // Now, you can add animations to your Spritemap!
        // You name the animation, pass in an array consisting of the frame numbers, and the frame rate (milliseconds per frame).
        animatedSprite.add("running", [0, 1, 2, 3], 50);

        // It's totally cool to repeat frames, too! Out of order is nuts, but also okay.
        animatedSprite.add("falling", [4, 4, 4, 5, 1], 50);

        // Now, you just play your animation like so:
        animatedSprite.play("running");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using Flashpunk's VarTween class like so:

```
var image:Image = (Image)(goombaEntity.graphic);
var sizeTween:VarTween = new VarTween();
sizeTween.tween(image, "height", 0, 0.5);
thisWorld.addTween(sizeTween, true);
```

This will make the Entity's height go from full height to 0 in half a second.  If you just want to change the Entity's height & width, you'll need to access its graphic and mess with that.